# How to get the file absolute path using javascript or ...?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript that used to upload files.
The problem is I can't get the absolute path using javascript.  Is there any other client-side scripting language that can be used to get the absolute path of the file and pass it to my javascript? I don't want to used server-side scripting language like php. Is this possible?
Just to get the path is fine..

Comment: Are you asking for a path on the client machine or the server?

Comment: Path on client machine. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: You need to use server side to upload a file so you can in upload script return the path to that file and use it in client.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the file path in client browsers.  For security concern it is restricted.  You will be given only the **fake path is shown with file name**.

Comment: Seriouusly... Why do you bother to answer more than 5 minutes after I marked as duplicate...

Comment: @dystroy I didn't loaded the comments due to my connectivity.  Side by side I was trying to do JSFiddle to shown the fakepath.  But it is getting saved.  My bad time with connectivity, sorry for being late.